# Merging Entity Framework Expression Trees

Tags: entity-framework

I'm looking for a way to merge multiple expression trees in order to build selectors for an Entity Framework query. The query knows which columns to select based on user-provided parameters. For example, a basic query returns ID/Name columns of an entity. If a parameter is explicitly set to also retrieve the Description column, then the query will return ID/Name/Description.

So, what I need it the code for the **MergeExpressions** method in the following code.

```
Expression<Func<T, TDto>> selector1 = x => new TDto
{
    Id = x.Id,
    Name = x.Name
}

Expression<Func<T, TDto>> selector2 = x => new TDto
{
    Description = x.Description
}

var selector = selector1;
if (includeDescription)
    selector = MergeExpressions(selector1, selector2);

var results = repo.All().Select(selector).ToList();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure for general case, but merging [`MemberInitExpression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberinitexpression(v=vs.110).aspx0) bodied lambdas like in your sample is relatively easy. All you need is to create another `MemberInitExpression` with combined [`Bindings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.memberinitexpression.bindings(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
static Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> MergeExpressions<TInput, TOutput>(Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> first, Expression<Func<TInput, TOutput>> second)
{
    Debug.Assert(first != null && first.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberInit);
    Debug.Assert(second != null && second.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberInit);
    var firstBody = (MemberInitExpression)first.Body;
    var secondBody = (MemberInitExpression)second.Body.ReplaceParameter(second.Parameters[0], first.Parameters[0]);
    var body = firstBody.Update(firstBody.NewExpression, firstBody.Bindings.Union(secondBody.Bindings));
    return first.Update(body, first.Parameters);
}
```

Note that the lambda expressions must be bound to one and the same parameters, so the above code uses the following parameter replacer helper to rebind second lambda body to the first lambda parameter:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Simple and clean solution. Thank you Ivan.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx).

Example:

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expr1 = (Customer c) => c.CompanyName.StartsWith("A");
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> expr2 = (Customer c) => c.CompanyName.Contains("B");

var expr3 = PredicateBuilder.And(expr1, expr2);
var query = context.Customers.Where(expr3);
```

or

```
var expr3 = expr1.And(expr2);
var query = context.Customers.Where(expr3);
```

Comment: PredicateBuilder only works with predicates, in my case TDto is not a bool.

Comment: @Joe You will have to refactor a bit to use PredicateBuilder. From my experience, simplest way to combine expressions for EF queries.

Comment: The question is an over-simplified version of a much complicated case. I cannot refactor. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of thing with extension methods. Its syntactically a bit nicer than using expression trees everywhere. I call this [composable repositories](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2015/9/8/composable_repositories).

I also wrote a tool ([LinqExpander](https://github.com/lukemcgregor/LinqExpander)) to combine the expression trees of different extension methods togeather, which is especially useful for doing projection (selects) from your database. This is only nessacary when you are doing things with sub-entities. (see my post here: [Composable Repositories -  Nesting extensions](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2016/10/24/composable_repositories_-_nesting_extensions))

usage would be something along the lines of:

```
var dtos = context.Table
              .ThingsIWant() //filter the set
              .ToDtos() //project from database model to something else (your Selector)
              .ToArray();//enumerate the set
```

ToDtos might look something like:

```
public static IQueryable<DtoType> ToDtos(this IQueryable<DatabaseType> things)
{
     return things.Select(x=> new DtoType{ Thing = x.Thing ... });
}
```

You want to merge two selects togeather (im assuming to avoid an underfetch but this seems a bit wierd). I would do this by using a projection like this:

```
context.Table
              .AsExpandable()
              .Select(x=>new {
                 Dto1 = x.ToDto1(),
                 Dto2 = x.ToDto2()
              })
              .ToArray();
```

if you really wanted it to return a single entity like this you could probably do something like:

```
context.Table
              .AsExpandable()
              .Select(x=> ToDto1(x).ToDto2(x));
```

but I havent ever tried this.

As this uses a sub projection you will need the .AsExpandable extensions.