# How to Combine Expressions of dynamic Types

Tags: c#, linq-expressions, c#-10.0

I would like to see if it I possible to AndAlso two expressions of type dynamic. This sample is very simplistic compared to what I am actually doing but it gets the point across. All examples I have seen using PedicateBuilder or ExpressionBuilder require the expressions to be of type bool and are generally being used as "Where" clauses. This one is returning a new, dynamic object.

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }   
    public string Comment { get; set; } 
}

Expression<Func<MyObject, dynamic>> e1 = i => new { MyName = i.Name };
Expression<Func<MyObject, dynamic>> e2 = i => new { MyValue = i.Value };
```

I am looking to get back a combined expression of e1 && e2. Am I going about this the right way?

**Update  1:**
I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40864678/1148554) but it expects input as MemberInitExpression and I have NewExpression which does not contain the bindings needed

Comment: The static type of `e1` is `dynamic` (i.e. `object`) but the runtime type will be of an anonymous class created by the compiler with a single property. The same for `e2`. These can't be combined with `AndAlso` that will just be a runtime error. (Try what you want statically and see the error when you run.) What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to combine e1 and e2 to form e3 which contains both MyName and MyValue properties

Comment: C# is a language of types, regardless of `dynamic`, `e1` and `e2` have types. Why do you think the boolean `&&` operator is relevant here? (What is the result of attempting: `(new { MyName = "a" }) && (new { MyValue = "b" })` ?)

Comment: If you could do what you want, what (runtime) type do you expect the result to be? You don't have an existing anonymous type with the two properties, do you expect to create a new type at runtime (possible, but a lot of work, and rarely worth it - in fact, using `dynamic` is rarely worth it.)

Comment: @NetMage - I get why you keep asking me WHY I want to do this. That is irrelevant. I want to know if I CAN do this. I am aware AndAlso is for boolean types and this is not the case. I also understand dynamic is in itself a type. I am curious if I CAN merge these two expressions together and get a single combined expression out of it

Comment: The answer to your question is yes. Do you have LINQPad? You can use the `Dump` method in LINQPad to view the compiler's construction of `e1` and `e2` (it calls the anonymous class constructor passing the values for the parameters). You can do the same once you have created `e1_2`.

Comment: Also, you are wrong about it being irrelevant. Otherwise you run the risk of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which is common when one doesn't really understand how to solve a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Given

```
Expression<Func<MyObject, dynamic>> e1 = i1 => new { MyName = i1.Name };
Expression<Func<MyObject, dynamic>> e2 = i2 => new { MyValue = i2.Value };
```

You can create a new Anonymous Type that will have both properties. I will create it manually:

```
var mo = new MyObject();
mo.Name = "a";
mo.Value = "1";
var make_e1_2 = new { MyName = mo.Name, MyValue = mo.Value };
```

Then you can extract the parameters and bodies from the `e1` and `e2` and use them to call the new types constructor:

```
// (MyObject i1)
var e1_2Parm = e1.Parameters[0];

// new { MyName = i1.Name }
var e1Body = (NewExpression)e1.Body;
// new { MyValue = i1.Value }
var e2Body = (NewExpression)e2.Body.Replace(e2.Parameters[0], e1_2Parm);

// .ctor(string MyName, string MyValue)
var e1_2Constructor = make_e1_2.GetType().GetConstructors().First();

// new { MyName = i1.Name, MyValue = i1.Value }
var e1_2Body = Expression.New(e1_2Constructor, e1Body.Arguments[0], e2Body.Arguments[0]);

// (MyObject i1) => new { MyName = i1.Name, MyValue = i1.Value }
var e1_2 = Expression.Lambda<Func<MyObject, dynamic>>(e1_2Body, e1_2Parm);
```

This code assumes the existence of a standard `ExpressionVisitor` extension that replaces any occurrence of one `Expression` with another as `Replace()`.
You can write your own easily or us the EF Core `ReplacingExpressionVisitor` class to create one.